# Run-Time error on add method VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My function's intent is explained in the docstring.  However, when I run it, I get a "Run-Time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set", and a line of code is highlighted, as indicated below.  I cannot find the source of this issue, especially since I am rather new to VBA.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
'==============================|Range_Collection FUNCTION|=============================='
' Given a collection and a range, add each value in that range to the collection, except
' for False values.
Function Range_Collection(col As Collection, rng As Range) As Collection

    Dim Val As Variant
    For Each Val In rng
        If Not Val.Value = False Then
            col.Add Val.Value ;************** THIS CODE IS HIGHLIGHTED************
        End If
    Next Val
    Set Range_Collection = col

End Function
```

Comment: `col.Add Val.Value,cstr(Val.Value)` ? This will give you an error if you try to add same item twice so you may have to envelope it between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: Unfortunately I received the same error after trying that.

Comment: See my Edit on the comment

Comment: I am no longer getting the error.  Do you know what the cause of it could have been?

Comment: I am stepping out for 1 hour. If you have any quesitons, please leave a comment below my question and I will answer it when i come back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

This is what I get when I run the code

[image]

Further to my comment, see this

The syntax is *col.add "Item","Key"*. The key has to be unique. If you have duplicate values then then use OERN as I suggested or use a unique key.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As New Collection

    For Each itm In Range_Collection(c, Range("A1:A5"))
        Debug.Print itm
    Next
End Sub
Function Range_Collection(col As Collection, rng As Range) As Collection

    Dim rVal As Variant

    For Each rVal In rng
        If Not rVal.Value = False Then
            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add rVal.Value, CStr(rVal.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next rVal

    Set Range_Collection = col
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Dim Val As Variant` to `Dim Val As Range`

Answer (score 1):

Also, **watch out** for *this* little "potential language oddity" ... *(in any language)*

When you wrote:

```
If Not Val.Value = False Then
```

... then you no doubt *intended* to say:  *(note the parentheses, carefully ...)*

```
 If Not (Val.Value = False) Then
```

... *(in other words, "not equal to")* ...

But most grammars actually bind the `Not` operator more tightly than a relational-operator such as `=`, producing what could be this *actual* interpretation, with no syntax-errors:

```
 If (Not Val.Value) = False Then
```

... *(in other words, "if `Val.Value` is **True**!")*

The compiler judges your statement to be "syntactically and semantically correct," as in fact it *is.*  But its **interpretation** of what you have written might not be what you thought it was.  If you include the parentheses as I have shown above, all ambiguity is removed.

- If you want *"not equal to"*, **always** use the appropriate operator.
- When using logical operators, use parentheses plentifully to make your intentions clear, both to the compiler and to other people.

Oddly enough, this sort of issue led to a bug in the *very first* program that I ever wrote:  which "was 6 lines long, took me 6 months to write (in BASIC for a timesharing computer, nevermind how long ago now), and had a bug in it."

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  I'm used to parenthesizing everything in Java so now with VBA I tend to get a little confused as many functions don't require parenthesis and some have different needs for them.

Comment: It's a very "loosey goosey" syntax ... which is sorta what you get when a language tries to be helpful, *and* which is one of the reasons why Java is *(ahem...)* "so very anal about parentheses and lots of other things.  Nothing wrong with either of the two languages, but they are very different animals written by two entirely different teams.